# Exchange body null exception even when it is there

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have the following code -

```
PdfRequest pdfRequest = new PdfRequest();
pdfRequest.setAppName("abc"));
pdfRequest.setId("D342");
String pdfRequestJson = mapper.toJson(pdfRequest);
producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders("direct:sendRoute", pdfRequestJson,
                                                null, String.class);    //line number 154
```

Route configuration of same is -

```
from("direct:sendRoute")
            .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
            .log("Sending data ${body} to queue") . //this log was never printed
            .toF("pdfQueueProducerBean:topic://%s", topicName)
            .end();
```

`mapper` is gson bean in above case

But while executing this code i am getting the following error -

```
 org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1379)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:622)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:467)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:260)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:309)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:305)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:342)
    at com.tasks.TriggerConsumer.triggerService(TriggerConsumer.java:154)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:407)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:278)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:251)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:103)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:562)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:500)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:990)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate$2.process(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:254)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:355)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:346)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:242)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:346)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:128)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:251)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

PdfRequest pojo -

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PdfRequest {
    private String id;
    private String appName;
    private String timestamp;
}
```

Obviously, my exchange body is not null as the object is being created just before sending it through producerTemplate ( and producerTemplate was autowired with default configuration if it matters)

Comment: Where does `digitalSignaturePdfRequest` come from? Can you share the full code?

Comment: That is `pdfRequest`, i missed renaming it while posting here. Updated the question too.

Comment: Thanks, we are now missing the `mapper` declaration though.

Comment: Ah sorry, its a gson bean, will update it too

Comment: Have you tried debugging or logging the value of `pdfRequestJson` to confirm that the value is not `null`?

Comment: I dont think this is about request. I expect it is OUT message from `direct:sendRoute` which is null. You can add log to your `direct:sendRoute` to see the body is there and the route is actually called. Could you share the `direct:sendRoute` definition? Also the stacktrace in question is just wrapping exception and there shoud be `caused by` showing real cause. Could you share full stacktrace?

Comment: Also, as a side note, if you are not sending headers, instead of setting them `null` you can use the `<T> T requestBody(Endpoint endpoint,
                Object body,
                Class<T> type)
              throws CamelExecutionException` method instead: https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/ProducerTemplate.html#requestBody(org.apache.camel.Endpoint,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class)

Comment: @SofoGial yes, i logged `pdfRequest` before `producerTemplate` and the object was actually printed and thanks for the suggestion, will use it future

Comment: @Bedla i have added the route configuration and `caused by` trace

Answer (score 0):

By using *producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(...)* you say that you want a response but by setting the exchange pattern *InOnly* on the route you tell it not to respond.

Your code looks like you don't actually need a response, so try:

```
producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:sendRoute", pdfRequestJson);
```

instead.